# Ansible: find file and loop over paths

Tags: ansible

Using an Ansible role. I would like to loop over a list of file paths, but I get an error:

```
template error while templating string: unexpected '/'.
String: {{/home/xyz/download.log}}
```

This is the `main.yml` for the "list_log_files" role:

```
- name: "find logs"
  find:
    paths: /
    patterns: 'download.log'
    recurse: yes
  register: find_logs

- name: "list log files"
  debug: var="{{ item.path }}"
  with_items: "{{ find_logs.files }}"
```

The find returns an array "files", each is a dictionary. The dictionary contains a path entry, which is what I am interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for `var` argument of `debug` module (with the value for your use case) is:

- In Ansible notation:

```yaml
debug: var=item.path
```

- In YAML notation:

```yaml
debug:
  var: item.path
```

Ansible modules' usage is fairy well documented and examples cover most users' needs. This is also true for the `debug` module, so [refer to the examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#examples) to check the basic syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately "debug: var: item.path" does not just print the path, it prints the entire contents of "item", but I only want the path. Maybe a filter would work?

Comment: Not exactly. Any `debug` task running in loop prints the whole `item` **in addition** to the variable specified, because that's how the module was written. Somebody just designed `debug` to be used for ...surprise... debugging.

Comment: Yes, I do have a lot to learn about Ansible. I really would like to get an array of paths from the "find" to pass on to other steps, but I don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: I don’t see any problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced same issue and above issue is same where I want list of path of each file to insert line. I use Jinja2 filter:

```
- name: fetch files
  find: paths=/var/tmp/ patterns='*.log'
  register: find_logs

- name: insert line
  lineinfile: dest={{ item }} line='my line' insertafter=EOF
  with_items: "{{ find_logs.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

{{ find_logs.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}

[Helpful Link](https://serverfault.com/a/970171)

[map()](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#map)

```
Applies a filter on a sequence of objects or looks up an attribute. 
This is useful when dealing with lists of objects but you are really 
only interested in a certain value of it.
```