# unable to copy file from local machine to ec2 instance in ansible playbook

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ansible

So I am running `scp -i ~/Downloads/ansible-benchmark.pem ~/Documents/cis-playbook/section-1.yaml ubuntu@ec2-18-170-77-90.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~/etc/ansible/playbooks/`

to transfer an ansible playbook I created with VSCODE the **section-1.yaml file**,

but I am coming up with an error `scp: /home/ubuntu/etc/ansible/playbooks/: No such file or directory`

the directory definitely exists in the ec2 instance, I did install ansible, but for some reason I don't know why it isn't recognising the directory.

Comment: show us the code that does `copy`. `The copy module copies a file from the local or remote machine to a location on the remote machine. ` https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/copy_module.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, you can check if is available

```
/home/ubuntu/etc/ansible/playbooks/
```

if that part is not available on target/source, you can use create a folder on ansible first then you can go for copy on target

You can use this issue [Ansible: find file and loop over paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819619/ansible-find-file-and-loop-over-paths)